# C# Filling Combo box with Column name of Database not Column values

Tags: c#, winforms

I know it's been asked many times and there's so many resources about this but believe me i tried those, Unfortunately same thing is always happen. I really don't know why my combo box column value is repeating. Can someone help me in doing these in a proper way. Did i forgot something here ? Thank you

```
 public void FillComboBox()
  {
        using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM employee_product", con))
            {
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        cbox_order.Items.Add("Code").ToString();
                        cbox_order.Items.Add("Model").ToString();
                        cbox_order.Items.Add("Itemdescription").ToString();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
  }
```

Here's the provided image
[image]

Comment: You're not using your reader: `cbox_order.Items.Add(reader["Code"].ToString());`  Not sure how you plan on cramming those 3 columns into a small display.

Comment: If you want to have only 3 values in the combo box then you don't need to do sqlCommand and o other things.  3 lines of `cbox_order.Items.Add` is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the code, you are basically just adding the strings "Code", "Model" and "Itemdescription" to the combobox. I guess you want rather something like:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
   cbox_order.Items.Add($"{reader["Code"]} {reader["Model"]} {reader["Itemdescription"]}");
}
```

In this snippet I am using the `reader` to get values of the columns in the returned row from the DB and then displaying joining those values in a single `string` that is then added to the `ComboBox` as an item.

### Update

If you know the column names, why not just do this?

```
public void FillComboBox()
{
    cbox_order.Items.Add("Code").ToString();
    cbox_order.Items.Add("Model").ToString();
    cbox_order.Items.Add("Itemdescription").ToString();
}
```

Comment: I tried that, It change my combo box value.. it now show the column values not the actual column names

Comment: And isn't it what you wanted?

Comment: @Anonymous If you only want the column names that you already know, you don't have to query the database.  Just add them once.

Comment: @MartinZikmund see the question title above once again, not column values

Comment: @LarsTech What do you mean by that ? are you saying that i simply add column names in the combo box properties ?

Comment: If you know the column names are "Code", "Model" and "Itemdescription" then why do you query the DB? Just add them and delete everything else in the code :-) .

Comment: I have updated my answer with the code you actually seem to want. If that is not it, then please explain your requirement better

Comment: OK. I accept it as my answer, i think that's better maybe i'm just thinking too hard

Comment: No problem, it happens :-) . Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try to close and dispose of reader and close the connection.

```
reader.close;
reader.dispose;

con.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

actually your not using your DataReader but you just add `Code`, `Model` and `ItemDescription` item for each row found with the MySQL query.

```
cbox_order.Items.Add("Code").ToString();
cbox_order.Items.Add("Model").ToString();
cbox_order.Items.Add("Itemdescription").ToString();
```

If you want to use the result of the MySQL query you can try this instead:

```
cbox_order.Items.Add(reader["Code"].ToString()).ToString(); // Change "Code" by the column name into the database
cbox_order.Items.Add(reader["Model"].ToString()).ToString(); // Change "Model" by the column name into the database
cbox_order.Items.Add(reader["Itemdescription"].ToString()).ToString(); // Change "Itemdescription" by the column name into the database
```

Don't forget to close the reader at the end

```
reader.Close();
```

**EDIT**

if you want the column name instead of data you can use this query, but that's useless if you already know the column name.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema='databasename' AND table_name='tablename'
```

Comment: I already tried that But no, it shows the column values of column names

Comment: So what do you exactly need? If you want the column names just fill it like you already do but remove the MySQL query because you already know the column name

Answer (score 0):

First load data into a `DataTable`:

```
var connection = @"Your connection string";
var command = "Your SELECT command text";
var table = new DataTable();
using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command, connection))
    adapter.Fill(table);
```

To show list of columns in a `ComboBox`:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToList();
comboBox1.ValueMember = "ColumnName";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ColumnName";
```

To show data in `DataGridView`:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

In above code I suppose you are going to show columns of the table which you also want to load its data at the same time. In case which you just want to load just column information, you can use:

```
adapter.FillSchema(table, SchemaType.Mapped);
```