# How to add the header row to combobox dynamically?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, row, addition

How to add the header row to combobox dynamically?  I have this form and I want fill that combobox2 with the header row dynamically.  I have searched everywhere and I did not find the answer...sorry for my bad English.

[image: Screenshot]

My Code:

```
OleDbcon.Close();
comboBox1.Items.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   String sheetName = dt.Rows[i]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
   sheetName = sheetName.Substring(0, sheetName.Length - 1);
   comboBox1.Items.Add(sheetName);
   comboBox2.Items.Add(****); // that I want do in it 
}
```

Comment: Is this `Winforms`, a web app?

Comment: winforms ,bro .with oledb conn.

Comment: Assuming `dt` is a DataTable, would you not just loop through the Columns grabbing the ColumnName property?

Comment: `comboBox2.DisplayMember = "ColumnName";
comboBox2.DataSource = dt.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().ToList();`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52370379/3110834

Comment: @StoneGiant How do i do that ??

Comment: @Jimi Doesn't work ..

Comment: Yes, it does. If it's not working for you, you should explain why, what result/error you have.