# How to display column names of my table (database) into combobox

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, winforms

How to display column name of my table (database) into combobox?

Comment: if you are using datatable just get the datatable and you should be able to reach its columns. so its name like `dtbl.Columns[0].Name`

Comment: and you ware unable to retrieve column name or list in combobox box ?

Comment: @parladneupane column name there are multiple columns in table. i need to bind it into combo box

Comment: well, you can access multiple columns, Did you get a list of the column first?

Comment: @parladneupane yes

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/combobox-in-C-Sharp/ will help or google it. There is plenty of examples.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52370379/3110834

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following to bind the column name into combo box. Here I have used `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to get the column name.

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindColumnnameToComboBox();
        }
        public void BindColumnnameToComboBox()   
        {
            DataRow dr;


            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=NiluNilesh;Initial Catalog=mynewdata;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS i where i.TABLE_NAME = 'Mark'", con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr.ItemArray = new object[] { 0, "--Select--" };
            dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);

            comboBox1.ValueMember = "COLUMN_NAME";

            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "COLUMN_NAME";
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;

            con.Close();


        }
```

Comment: so what `InitializeComponent();` will do ?

Comment: It is automatically crated to create and define user interface, controls in windows application.

Comment: like bootstrapping ?, i guess, documentation available there, thanks

Comment: Yes in windows application it work as bootstrapping- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297079/very-simple-definition-of-initializecomponent-method

Comment: hmm, Interesting function , thanks

Comment: [Set hint or watermark or default text for ComboBox without adding it as item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50972125/3110834)

Comment: [C# Filling Combo box with Column name of Database not Column values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52370379/3110834) Without need to another query.

Comment: @ Reza Aghaei I have already provided code for that as answer.